# using a $_GET id to filter a mysql_fetch_array in PHP

Tags: php

So I have a query that I am returning all of the items into a mysql_fetch_array. Now, I know I could write another query and just select the items I need into a seperate query but, is there a way to just filter from the larger query what I want dependent on $_GET?

So, in english the user comes from a hyperlink that has ?id=1 and I peform a while that gets the all the values but, only display the $_GET['id'] items in a list

```
<?php //give ma all values but only echo out list of the $_GET['id'] in the url
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    $id = $rowvideo["id"];
    $title = $rowvideo["title"];
    $length = $rowvideo["length"];
}
echo("<li><a href='#'>". $title." " .$length. "</a></li>");
?>
```

Hope this makes sense. Thank you all.

Comment: I see a major hole for SQL injection here.

Comment: htmlentries($_GET) then?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII really? I see no query at all.

Comment: Where is the SQL injection? The OP wants to filter after the query.

Comment: Don't query and fetch rows you don't intend to use.  if `$_GET['id']` is non-empty, use it to filter the query's `WHERE` clause. Otherwise get all rows.

Comment: @Michael he said he wants to do the filtering IN the query.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Yes, and its a little speculative to assume the OP will do no filtering or validation any kind on the value when used in the query...

Comment: Inside the while loop just do a if($row['id']==intval($_GET['id']) {... do your stuff here ...} P.S. $row and $rowvideo differ!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want a second query to get *just what you need*, a simple-`if-statement` in your loop should work:

```
<?php
$getId = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : false;
//give ma all values but only echo out list of the $_GET['id'] in the url
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $title = $row["title"];
    $length = $row["length"];

    if ($id == $getId) {
        echo("<li><a href='#'>". $title." " .$length. "</a></li>");
    }
}
?>
```

Note that I declared `$getId` outside of the loop to prevent having to use `isset()` during every iteration. If you don't verify if it's set and attempt to use it it will throw an `undefined index` warning - assuming you have `error_reporting` turned on (with that level enabled).

Alternatively, you could use PHP's [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) on the data after you've parsed it all:

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) $results[] = $row;
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $filtered = array_filter($results, function($element) use ($_GET['id']) { return ($element['id'] == $_GET['id']); });
    $results = $filtered;
}
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo("<li><a href='#'>". $result['title']." " .$result['length']. "</a></li>");
}
```

My personal opinion would be to be more efficient and write the second query though, assuming of course you don't actually need all of the results when an `id` is specified. It would be as simple as:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    $query = 'SELECT id, title, length FROM table WHERE id=' . (int)$_GET['id'];
} else {
    $query = 'SELECT id, title, length FROM table';
}
// your existing code as-is
```

Comment: I went with this option. Is there any security downside to this?

Comment: @MIguel Not really a "downside", however, there are issues with the way you output data into the HTML which can easily lead to Cross-Site-Scripting (XSS) attacks. You can mitigate them by using [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) or [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) given the exact way you use them. I don't know how your query looks to fetch the results so I can't speak regarding SQL Injection - my example query, however, would prevent it (though additional input-validation wouldn't help).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php //give ma all values but only echo out list of the $_GET['id'] in the url
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $rowvideo["id"];
    $title = $rowvideo["title"];
    $length = $rowvideo["length"];
    if ($id == $_GET['id']) { // or even ===
      echo("<li><a href='#'>". $title." " .$length. "</a></li>");
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: you've mismatched your brackets $result)) <- here

Comment: @Waygood He copy+pasted directly from the OP's code - error exists there too.

Answer (score 0):

A little more clarity here:

This will allow the filter by id in the url by specifying id=xxx, IF xxx is an integer that is positive. So id of 'bob' or -1 will not filter the results still giving all results

```
$filter=false;
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $filter_id=intval($_GET['id']);
    if($id>0) $filter=true;
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if( (!$filter) || ( ($filter) && ($filter_id==$row['id']) ) )
    {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $title = $row["title"];
        $length = $row["length"];

        // do other stuff here
    }
}
```

I also changed $rowvideo to $row as this is the array you used to fetch the results.